Find the maximum j – i such that arr[j] > arr[i] (Distance maximising problem) in kdb
Find the maximum j – i such that arr[j] > arr[i] (Distance maximising problem)
Output: 6  (j = 7, i = 1)
q)list: 34 8 10 3 2 80 30 33 1

q)func:{{first[y _ x],/: (y+1) _ x}[x] each y}

q)func[list;til count list]
(34 8;34 10;34 3;34 2;34 80;34 30;34 33;34 1)
(8 10;8 3;8 2;8 80;8 30;8 33;8 1)
(10 3;10 2;10 80;10 30;10 33;10 1)
(3 2;3 80;3 30;3 33;3 1)
(2 80;2 30;2 33;2 1)
(80 30;80 33;80 1)
(30 33;30 1)
,33 1
()

q)asc r where {(x 1)>(x 0)} each r:raze  func[list;til count list]
2  30
2  33
2  80
3  30
3  33
3  80
8  10
8  30
8  33
8  80
10 30
10 33
10 80
30 33
34 80

I am struck here to find the final result, please suggest on this.

Part of your issue is that you're losing the "positional information" embedded in the original list when pairing, razing and sorting. i.e. from the sorted razed result you have no way to link back to the original list order. As rian pointed out you can manage that by keeping it tabular and/or making use of the built-in indexing.
A non-tabular approach which also keeps track of indexes is:
q){sums{(x?m;m:max x)}max each i!where'[0<x-/:x]-i:til count x}34 8 10 3 2 80 30 33 1
1 7


This is not optimal/optimised but tables can be useful structures when thinking through problems.
Make a table from the list and store the indices as ind along with the array values arr:
q)t:{`arr xdesc ([] arr:x;ind:til count x)}[list]
q)t
arr ind
-------
80  5
34  0
33  7
30  6
10  2
8   1
3   3
2   4
1   8

Calulate index offsets off to each value > the current arr value and store their ind:
q)t:update calc:{[x;y]select ind,off:y-ind from t where x>arr,y>ind}'[arr;ind] from t
q)t
arr ind calc
---------------------------------------
80  5   +`ind`off!(0 2 1 3 4;5 3 4 2 1)
34  0   +`ind`off!(`long$();`long$())
33  7   +`ind`off!(6 2 1 3 4;1 5 6 4 3)
30  6   +`ind`off!(2 1 3 4;4 5 3 2)
10  2   +`ind`off!(,1;,1)
8   1   +`ind`off!(`long$();`long$())
3   3   +`ind`off!(`long$();`long$())
2   4   +`ind`off!(`long$();`long$())
1   8   +`ind`off!(`long$();`long$())

ungroup for final filtering:
q)t:ungroup t
q)t
arr ind calc
--------------------
80  5   `ind`off!0 5
80  5   `ind`off!2 3
80  5   `ind`off!1 4
80  5   `ind`off!3 2
80  5   `ind`off!4 1
33  7   `ind`off!6 1
33  7   `ind`off!2 5
33  7   `ind`off!1 6
33  7   `ind`off!3 4
33  7   `ind`off!4 3
30  6   `ind`off!2 4
30  6   `ind`off!1 5
30  6   `ind`off!3 3
30  6   `ind`off!4 2
10  2   `ind`off!1 1

Extract rows with largest offset:
q)select from t where calc[;`off] = max calc[;`off]
arr ind calc
--------------------
33  7   `ind`off!1 6

Output: Calculated offset calc[;`off] maxiumum is 6 from index ind 7 to calc[;`ind] 1
